# Reading from a file path having singlequotes in the file name

Tags: r

I need to provide a program for a third party for executing it at their end and their file path has single quotes(') in their file name as in 
"C:\Users\JD\Document\JD's\file.xlsx". How can we read this file?

Comment: You surrounded the filename with single quotes int double quotes, and I expect this should work with most R APIs.

Comment: Please read [How to Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and update your question. What approach(es) have you already tried, and what error(s) are you experiencing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think that R suppose to have with it much of a problem.
So, this works:

```
df <- readxl::read_excel("C:/Users/JD/Document/JD's/file.xlsx")
```